# Dictionary value as function to be called when key is accessed, without using "()"

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary, callback

I have a dictionary that has values sometimes as strings, and sometimes as a functions. For the values that are functions is there a way to execute the function without explicitly typing `()` when the key is accessed?

Example:

```
d = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: fn_1}
d[3]() # To run function
```

I want:

```
d = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: magic(fn_1)}
d[3] # To run function
```

Comment: Why without `()`?  Don't knit a sweater around a button...

Comment: Don't do this. `Explicit is better than implicit`. The meaning in your code is to look up a function and call it; so the code *should look like* you are doing exactly that. As an aside, mixing types like that is a bad idea; you need to check whether you have a string first (since you can't call the string), and that makes your life harder.

Comment: ... But on reflection, it sounds like you really have a *design* question, and should be asking a question that more closely reflects what you really want to do. I.e., why do you have this dictionary in the first place?

Comment: It sounds like instead of writing `d[3]`, you should be calling some function `some_func(3)`, and the function should index the dict and call the value if the value is a callable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another possible solution, is to create a custom dictionary object that implements this behavior:

```
>>> class CallableDict(dict):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         val = super().__getitem__(key)
...         if callable(val):
...             return val()
...         return val
...
>>>
>>> d = CallableDict({1: "A", 2: "B", 3: lambda: print('run')})
>>> d[1]
'A'
>>> d[3]
run
```

A [perhaps more idiomatic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) would be to use `try/except`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    val = super().__getitem__(key)
    try:
        return val()
    except TypeError:
        return val
```

Note however the method above is really for completness. I would not reccomend using it. [As pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106779/dictionary-value-as-function-to-be-called-when-key-is-accessed-without-using/46106852#comment79239880_46106852), it would mask `TypeError`'s raised by the function. You could test the exact content of `TypeError`, but at that point, you'd be better of using the LBYL style.

Comment: EAFP - `try: return val(); except TypeError: return val`?

Comment: @AChampion Eh, I could use EAFP instead. In some cases, I really don't think it matters to much :) I really wasn't thinking about it when I posted my answer.

Comment: EAFP hides TypeErrors that occur inside the called function in this case. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @PekkaKlärck Yeah, your right. I see that clearly now. I guess I was distracted when adding it to my answer, and wasn't thinking about the potential consequences of using it. I'll edit.

Comment: In this example the return value of `d[3]` would be `None`, right? The printing of `"run"` is a side effect.

Comment: @HåkenLid Sure. But the `lambda` function I used was just for exemplary purposes.

Comment: Essentially this just moves the call to the function "with parentheses" inside the callable: how is this better than just calling the function itself?

Comment: Primarily, it could be considered more compact and convenient than having to write parenthesis after each key index to a function. @gented This answer is more for the OP though. Personally, I would probably just stick with calling the function in the dictionary explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's (easily) possible with the standard library but you could use `lazy_object_proxy.Proxy` from the module [`lazy_object_proxy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazy-object-proxy) (it's third party so you need to install it):

```
>>> import lazy_object_proxy
>>> def fn_1():
...     print('calculation')
...     return 1000
...
>>> d = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: lazy_object_proxy.Proxy(fn_1)}
>>> print(d[3])
calculation
1000
```

Comment: Ah, very interesting solution. That library looks like it would be very useful for time consuming computations. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

1. declare the dictionary with its keys and the name of each
2. function without the()

   functions = {'1': function1, '2':fuction2, '3':fuction3 ,...}
3. pass the function/value by using the method get, which returns None
4. if the key doesn't exists
   `action = functions.get(key)`
5. call the function ,which is stored in the var action, + ()
   `action()`
6. your function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `callable()` to check if variable is, well, callable:

```
d = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: fn_1}
if callable(d[3]):
    d[3]()
else:
    d[3]
```

Comment: The asked specifically said without using `()` when the function is called

Answer (score -3):

Another solution: you can also pass some class method decorated using `@property`:

```
class Test:
    @property
    def method(self):
        return 'X'

d = {'a': 1, 'b': Test().method}
print(d)
print(d['a'])
print(d['b'])
```

Comment: This isn't a function that is called when the key is accessed.  It just sets the dictionary value when defined:  `{'a': 1, 'b': 'X'}`