# How to call class method from dict declared inside Class?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to create a dict within a class with keys as prompt-commands and class methods as values, but I'm getting below when trying to run the module

`cmd = {'-v': self.view_leagues(),
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

I do not understand why I'm not able to do this?

Example code below:

```
class CLIStats:

    cmd = {'-v': self.view_leagues(),
           'exit': 'sys.exit()',
           'Back To Home': '-b',
           'View Stats Type': '-s',
           'Help' : '-h' }

    def __init__(self):
        self.leagues = {'EN_PR': ['2019/2020', '2018/2019']}

    def view_leagues(self):
        for league in self.leagues.keys():
            print("{: <10}".format(league), end="")
        print('\n')


def main():
    interface = CLIStats()
    print(interface.cmd.keys())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need declare the variables inside `__init__()`. Try this:

```
class CLIStats:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leagues = {'EN_PR': ['2019/2020', '2018/2019']}
        self.cmd = {'-v': self.view_leagues(),
               'exit': 'sys.exit()',
               'Back To Home': '-b',
               'View Stats Type': '-s',
               'Help' : '-h' }

    def view_leagues(self):
        for league in self.leagues.keys():
            print("{: <10}".format(league), end="")
        print('\n')


def main():
    interface = CLIStats()
    print(interface.cmd.keys())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to create `cmd` ad standalone variable use the following code:

```
class CLIStats:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leagues = {'EN_PR': ['2019/2020', '2018/2019']}

    def view_leagues(self):
        for league in self.leagues.keys():
            print("{: <10}".format(league), end="")
        print('\n')


def main():
    interface = CLIStats()
    cmd = {'-v': interface.view_leagues(),
           'exit': 'sys.exit()',
           'Back To Home': '-b',
           'View Stats Type': '-s',
           'Help' : '-h' }
    print(cmd.keys())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the input! If I may ask, why must `cmd` be declared in the `__init__` method and cannot not be a stand alone variable?

Comment: Because you are using a function which is internal to class and you need to add `self` to `cmd` because you are accessing in `print(interface.cmd.keys())` using the instance of the class..

Comment: I understand! Because the problem is the when `cmd` is declared in `__init__()` the `self.view_leagues()` is called when executing the module, but I want the method to be executed on command.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense on why I can't do what I was trying to do!

Comment: I've been testing above and it doesn't work as intended, that functions inside `cmd` are executed when `cmd` is declared. But values inside `cmd` should only be executed if the user prompts the key to that specific value

Comment: @MisterButter you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106779/dictionary-value-as-function-to-be-called-when-key-is-accessed-without-using